# C++ assigning managed pointers to an object with and without the address operator "%"

Tags: datetime, pointers, c++-cli, memory-address, managed

I am relatively new to C++ and am learning how to use pointers, but I ran into something that has really confused me about assigning them. I have code similar to the following:

```
DateTime^ dt;

...

while(true)
{
    if(!dt)
    {
        //both of these work - compile and the loop will break after a minute
        //dt = DateTime::Now;
        dt = %DateTime::Now;
    }
    else if ((DateTime::Now - *dt).TotalMilliseconds > 60000)
    {
         break;
    }
}
```

Why do both of these work? From my understanding the `dt = %DateTime::Now` sets the `dt` pointer to the reference of the object returned by `DateTime::Now` which makes since to me. But what then is happening for in `dt = DateTime::Now` because if `DateTime::Now` does return an object then shouldn't it give me a cannot convert `DateTime` to `DateTime^` error? It seems like in order for this second one to work, `DateTime::Now` would need to return the reference of the `DateTime` object created by `DateTime::Now` in which case shouldn't the first one `dt = %DateTime::Now` give the similar error of cannot convert `DateTime^^` to `DateTime^` or do smart pointers work differently than normal pointers?

Comment: Wrong language. Not C++.

Comment: What is `^` after type and `%` before "pointer"??? Are you sure you are learning C++? :)

Comment: This is C++ with managed extensions.  It is how you use C++ to write .NET code.

Comment: @Darryl So, it isn't C++. Maybe you can help find the appropriate tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> sets the dt pointer to the reference of the object returned by DateTime::Now

That's where you went wrong, DateTime::Now does **not** return an object.  It returns a *value*, DateTime is a value type.  The distinction between reference types and value types is completely absent in C++ but is a very big deal in .NET.  You must understand it to write efficient code, this is very much *not* efficient.

> DateTime^ dt;

That's where the train jumped off the track, since DateTime is a value type you should declare this variable *without* the ^ hat.  Sadly the C++/CLI compiler allows this syntax and actually implements it.  The variable stores a *boxed* copy of the value.  Intentionally boxing values is something you always want to avoid, the boxing conversion is not cheap.  And the entire point of .NET having value types at all was to make programs fast.

But yes, as you discovered the C++/CLI compiler knows how to box values without you having to be explicit about it.  While it should be avoided, it is not unusual at all that values are boxed sometimes.  No way to call the virtual ToString() method otherwise for example.  So you don't have to use `%`.  Boxing creates the illusion that all value types derive from System::Object.

> if(!dt)

I have to assume that this is what you were really after, detecting that a variable is "not initialized".  There's a much more efficient pattern for that in that .NET, you use the Nullable<> type instead.  Like this:

```
Nullable<DateTime> dt;
while (true) {
    if (!dt.HasValue) {
        dt = DateTime::Now;
    }
    else if ((DateTime::Now - dt.Value).TotalMilliseconds > 60000) {
        break;
    }
}
```

Which can be improved in *many* ways, you avoid the halt-and-catch-fire version with:

```
System::Threading::Thread::Sleep(60000);
```

Comment: Isn't Nullable basically a boxed value type?  I would expect the version of code you suggested to be essentially identical to the original code.

Comment: No, Nullable is a struct.  A value type.  No boxing occurs anywhere in the snippet.  It was added to .NET to *avoid* boxing.  Compilers know how it works, they set the HasValue field to *true* without having to explicitly write that assignment.